# What is the new process to follow Substrate releases for the polkadot-sdk monrepo

Tags: upgrade, versioning, releases

In the Substrate repo, it was common to update to polkadot release-branches to version the Substrate crates. Will this still be the case for chains based on the monorepo version of Substrate? Will there be an option for following versions of Substrate crates themselves?

Answer (score 2):

You can find all crates released to crates.io under the [`parity-crate-owner`](https://crates.io/users/parity-crate-owner?sort=recent-updates) user.
With each release of the Parity Polkadot node these crates are being released to crates.io too.

You can see that the runtimes maintained by the Polkadot Technical Fellowship are already pointing their deps to these crates. Change made in PR [#28](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/pull/28)

For more context: https://forum.polkadot.network/t/publish-substrate-to-crates-io/949/28?u=alejandro